# Move Lifejacket and Lifeboat to Answer Badges section in Help Center

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, help-center, lifejacket-lifeboat-badges

The new blog post [Adios to Unfriendly Badges: Ahoy, Lifejacket and Lifeboat](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/06/18/adios-to-unfriendly-badges-ahoy-lifejacket-and-lifeboat/)  mentions the new badges [Lifejacket](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/313/lifejacket) and [Lifeboat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/314/lifeboat) are *answer* badges, but they are listed on the [Help Center page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges) under Question Badges:

[image]

Since you earn these primarily by posting an answer (you're not required to do anything about the question, though editing it will probably help), they definitely belong to the Answer Badges.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems to be [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) now.

[image: Livejacket und -boat are Answer badges now.]