# Lifejacket and Lifeboat badges should be categorized as answer badges, not question badges

Tags: bug, badges, lifejacket-lifeboat-badges

I noticed the [two new badges that just rolled out](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/06/18/adios-to-unfriendly-badges-ahoy-lifejacket-and-lifeboat/): "Lifejacket" and "Lifeboat". These are awarded to answerers for answering a negatively-scored question that later goes on to earn a positive score, and the answer itself is also upvoted.

According to the blog post, these badges are awarded to the answerers, not the questioners. (If it's not clear, the text "*we’re retroactively awarding these badges so if **you’ve rescued any questions in the past**, that achievement will be recognized within about 24 hours*" implies it.)

However, both of these badges are currently listed in the "Question Badges" section of the [badges page](/badges). As these badges are awarded to the answerers, these should be listed as "Answer Badges".

Comment: Darn it...missed it by a minute! [Move Lifejacket and Lifeboat to Answer Badges section in Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329677/move-lifejacket-and-lifeboat-to-answer-badges-section-in-help-center)

Comment: Isn't this post super obsolete? What are the chances that these two badges get misplaced or miscategorized again anytime in the future?